# C# performing bulk update on table from multiple threads without a deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, multithreading, bulkupdate

I have written a following piece of code:

```
public void BulkUpdateItems(List<Items> items)
        {
            var bulk = new BulkOperations();

            using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"connstring"))
                {
                    bulk.Setup()
                    .ForCollection(items)
                    .WithTable("Items")
                    .AddColumn(x => x.QuantitySold)
                    .BulkUpdate()

                    .MatchTargetOn(x => x.ItemID)
                    .Commit(conn);

                }
                trans.Complete();
            }
        }
```

With using a SQLBulkTools library... But the problem here is when I run this procedure from multiple threads at a time I run on deadlocks...

And the error states that a certain process ID was deadlocked or something like that....

Is there any alternative to perform a bulk update of 1 table from multiple threads in an efficient way?

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about that API but a quick read suggests a few things you could try. I would try them in the order listed.

1. Use a smaller [batch size](http://bulk-operations.net/batch), and/or set the batch timeout higher. This will let each thread take turns.
2. Use a [temporary table](http://bulk-operations.net/temporary-table). This will allow the threads to work independently.
3. Set the [options](http://bulk-operations.net/sql-server) to use a table lock.  If you lock the whole table, different threads won't be able to lock different rows, so you shouldn't get any deadlocks.

Comment: If the OP does your suggestion #3, wouldn't that make his/her use of multiple threads pointless?

Comment: I'm guessing the "multiple threads" issue is caused by the fact that the OP is using ASP.NET, and there is one thread per HTTP request.  But you are correct in that it will cause the updates to be done in series rather than in parallel.  Using a table lock will allow the OP to avoid having to code his own queuing system.  On the other hand, it is possible these bulk operations will cause HTTP requests to time out.

Comment: I had missed the ASP.Net tag. I was thinking the threads were intentional and created by OP's code. Your reply makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The deadlock message is coming from SQL Server - it means that one of your connections is waiting on a resource locked by another, and that second connection is waiting on a resource held on the first.

If you are trying to update the same table, you are likely running into a simple SQL locking issue and nothing really to do with C#. You need to think more thoroughly about the implications of doing a bulk update on multiple threads; its probably (depending on the percentage of the table you are updating) better to do this on a single connection and use a queue style of mechanism to de-conflict the individual calls.

Answer (score -1):

Try

lock
{
....
}

What this will do is, when one process is executing the code within the curly braces, it will cause other processes to wait until the first one is finished.  In that way, only one process will execute the block at a time.

Comment: `lock` does not synchronize multiple processes, and even if it did, a database can be interacted with from entirely different machines entirely.  The synchronization needs to be handled at the DB level.

Comment: @Servy, I think the scenario is multithreading in one process, no?

Comment: @dsolimano No, it's not.  It's a database throwing an error because some interaction with some other connection to the database is causing a deadlock.  Databases are not local to a single process.

Comment: @Servy, maybe.  But, if this is part of a nightly data load, at a time when there aren't other database users, which this question suggests but doesn't state . . . it's entirely possible this one process is stepping on its own feet, I've done it myself before.

Comment: @dsolimano Sure, but just because it's less *likely* that there are other people on doesn't mean  you can assume nobody else will ever be on.  The code still needs to be written to function when there *are* other people on.